# Recovering from Tarball in /usr/bin missing Software

Tags: linux, operating-system, debian, backup

I've been backing up a Debian system for some time and had a new system installation recently.

The command for a tarball goes something along the lines of

`sudo tar -cvpzf "filename.tar.gz" "directory_for_backup"`

After placing some software from said tarball in /usr/bin and prompting

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y`

the software isn't listed in registry.

Is there any other step that's needed to re-instate software without installing from a .deb or apt-get?

In addition to writing new files like vlc some files like dpkg cause system wide shock.

I've tried overwriting /var folder and that has recursive issues.

My expectation was to install the exact same parameters and have access to get software working out of the backup.

Not sure what a symlink is but my next attempt is researching that.

Comment: Note: you should not modify manually `/usr/bin`. It is not your domain. Programs outside distribution (or without a package) should be put in /usr/local/bin, or in /opt, or in your $HOME/bin. If you want to install packages previously installed, use `dpkg --get-selection` to create a file with package you selected, and `dpkg --set-selection` to set the selection (possibly you want to filter only the packages to be installed, and not do disintall others). Then package manager know, and so you can tell it to follow your selections. Do not use tar. it create confusing/inconsistent system setting